# what is the difference between these .loc() codes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I am wondering what is the difference between these two lines:

```
data.loc[(data['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'].isnull()==True)]['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS']
data.loc[(data['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'].isnull()==True),'MINIMUM_PAYMENTS']
```

When I try to do:

```
data.loc[(data['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'].isnull()==True),'MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'] = data['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'].mean()
```

it works, but

```
data.loc[(data['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'].isnull()==True)]['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'] = data['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'].mean()
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `data.loc[(data['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'].isnull()==True)]['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS']` accesses the `MINIMUM_PAYMENTS` column on a copy created from `data.loc[(data['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'].isnull()==True)]` instead of using the `loc` accessor to set the results to the `data` dataframe with `data.loc[(data['MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'].isnull()==True),'MINIMUM_PAYMENTS'] = ... `